# Spark reading from a position delimited file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I have a problem where I am trying to split a file along n character length records for a distributed system. I have the functionality for breaking up the record and map it to the proper names on a record level but need to go from the file to being on the system to breaking up the file and passing it out to the nodes in n length sized pieces to be split and processed.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and desired output?

Comment: File abc12.34abd00.01 Record length: 8 Records sent to cluster nodes: abc12.34 abd00.01. I have a function to break up the actual record. I just need to connect the file in the HDFS file system to the broken records sent to the individual nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into the specs for the SparkContext object and there is a method to pull in a file from the Hadoop environment and load it as a byte array data frame. The function is byteRecords.